# Can Bool value be multiple with tuple

Tags: python-3.x

Whats the concept, why 7 is printed and 5 isn't?
What operations are these?

```
x,y=5,0
test=x**y>0
ans=(5,7)[test]
print(ans)
```

Comment: `True==1` and that is acting as an index. Try `(5,7)[False]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because test will be true so ( 1 )

and your tuple have two values : 0 -> 5 , 1 -> 7 ,

it's logic that ans will containt (5,7)[1] = 7

Comment: @Ashen-1: Don't feel stupid. Learn a new Python idiom!

Comment: Note that this is not pythonic. It's better to use an if statement.

Comment: Prior to Python 2.5 with the `x=this if condition else that` ternary, a common method to assign one of two values was exactly this: `x=(value_if_false, value_if_true)[predicate]` See [PEP 308](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/)